# Website copy not mine

Tags: html, web

1 month ago i've made my website portfolio and i was daily looking for auto referencement since i saw other website with the same name AND the same content in the top results of Google and Qwant..

So, i've updated my website with a little alert to prevent from malicious use of my website but for now i'd like to know how they can copy my website so easily and fast, i've upadted my website with this alert and instantly it this alert was on those copy ..

Any idea to prevent this ? and maybe misconfiguration of my server but not sure of this one.

- Original : http://corentindehay.me/
- Copy : u4lab [dot] com
- Copy : hongluchua [dot] fr

Thanks

Comment: http://u4lab.com/ is not reachable from italy

Comment: http://www.u4lab.com/

Answer (score 2):

A ping to those two domains show that it's the same server that handles the requests:

1. corentindehay.me 5.196.8.82
2. hongluchua.fr 5.196.8.82

The third domain is not reachable from here (Belgium).

Thus, what you can do is to configure Apache/Nginx to only serve domain corentindehay.me. By default Apache serves requests with vhost 000_default.conf if I remember well.
You can define a new vhost that only serve your domain via something like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/yourPortfolio
ServerName corentindehay.me
ServerAlias www.corentindehay.me
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to change the default vhost's behavior. More info can be found here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/examples.html

Beside that, you have no real solution to block someone to copy your website as the source code is public. But I really don't see any reason to copy a Portfolio...

You can also enable SSL. Certificates are linked to a specific domain and served by your webserver. So in that case, you produce a certificate for corentindehay.me which will only be valid for that domain. People accessing your server with a different domain will see an error about invalid certificate.

Comment: the weird thing is that the edits on the original website reflects automatically on the copies.

Comment: @valerio0999 Because it's the same server. There are just two domains pointing to the same web server.

Comment: Strange , didn't saw that !
It's nginx hosted , any idea how to correct this ?

Comment: @CorentinDy I updated my answer with an example of vhost

Comment: Nice for Apache, but i think i totally missed something with Nginx configuration, thanks for help btw i will make a clean Nginx configuration quickly !

Comment: @CorentinDy BTW, frauduleuse, not froduleuse. ;)

Answer (score -5):

better you can use css and Javascript copy protected codes. This will not allow the user to select anything from your page...you can also disable the control keys using their ascii values..

This codes can help you

You

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=false;}
document.onkeydown=function(e){
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=true;
if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) &amp;&amp; isCtrl == true){
// alert(&#8216;Keyboard shortcuts are cool!&#8217;);
return false;}}
var isNS = (navigator.appName == &quot;Netscape&quot;) ? 1 : 0;
if(navigator.appName == &quot;Netscape&quot;) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
function mischandler(){
return false;}
function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
</script>
```

this post for more better solution
http://www.droidadda.org/2017/03/how-to-show-your-blog-post-link.html

Comment: This will only annoy regular users and in no way prevents anyone from copying the source.

Comment: So year 2003 :P